# freopen() on OSX 10.10.3

Tags: macos, pthreads, io-redirection

I have a C program which spawns a pthread to act as an interactive terminal: reading lines from `stdin` & acting upon them.  The program acts as a kind of shell, `fork`-ing off processes; each process so created has its `stdin` re-directed using a call to `freopen()` before using `exec` to load the new executable.

Before the interactive thread is started, all works fine.  Once it has started (or, more specifically, whenever it is waiting for input), calls to `freopen()` hang.  Is there some way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that is working for me can be found in R.'s answer to [Is close/fclose on stdin guaranteed to be correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/288062/535275)

Basically, the idea is to open the file you want to redirect to, duplicate that to stdin, and then close the file description just opened.