# loop running infinite time after calling display function

Tags: c, switch-statement, infinite-loop, do-while

```cpp
do
{
    printf("1 :Enter Company Deatils\n");
    printf("2 :Display stoke Deatils\n");
    printf("0 :Exit\n");
    printf("\nEnter num: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    switch (n)
    {
        case 1:
            enter();
            break;
        case 2:
            display();
            break;
    }
}
while (n != 0);
```

When I enter `2` to call display function after that `scanf()` not taking any input and running loop for infinite time.

```
void display_d(){
    point c1;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("company_det.txt","r");
    while(fread(&c1,sizeof(point),1,fptr)){
        printf("\n%s %s %d\n",c1.company_name,c1.bla.date,c1.bla.price);
    }
    fclose(stdin);
}
```

this is my display function

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` leads to undefined behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Comment: This looks like C. Is the c++ tag relevant?

Comment: @yun after removing fflush(stdin); still having same problem

Comment: Then the `display()` function must contain an infinite loop? The code looks fine otherwise.

Comment: void display()
{
    point c1;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("company_det.txt", "r");
    while (fread(&c1, sizeof(point), 1, fptr))
    {
        printf("\n%s %s %d\n", c1.company_name, c1.bla.date, c1.bla.price);
    }
    fclose(stdin);}        ///my display functin

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include this function?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more info and a [mre]. Down here in the comments it gets bent and lost.

Comment: `fclose(stdin)` causes any attempt at reading from `stdin`, such as by `scanf` later, to invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Please replace both function calls by simple prints to narrow down the location of the problrm. What happens?

Comment: you can check display() function i have just edited the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `display_d()` closes `stdin`. When the function returns, `scanf` will try to use `stdin` to read another digit. This is *undefined behavior* ([see answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288062/is-close-fclose-on-stdin-guaranteed-to-be-correct)).

You probably meant to close the file instead of `stdin`.

Also, the return value of `fopen` should be checked. It will be `NULL` if `fopen` failed to open the file.