# Forking an interactive program from a curses process causes keyboard interference

Tags: c, fork, ncurses, curses

From a curses interface, a user may fork a feh instance to view an image. The curses interface has `hjkl` navigation which should not be blocked as the image is viewed.

```
void display_file(void) {
    def_prog_mode();
    endwin();

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (!pid) {
        execl("/usr/bin/feh", "feh", "/home/abc/main/violet.jpg", NULL);
    }

    reset_prog_mode();
    wrefresh(state_of_curses.a_win);
    wrefresh(state_of_curses.b_win);
}
```

This opens feh, and when feh is the active window, `hjkl` navigation affects feh only (as normal). But when the curses terminal is active, all keys seem to be sent randomly either to curses or to feh (ie `hjkl` may move the image, when it should only affect curses).

Why is this so? What is the right way to achieve the desired effect?

- The program works as desired if I run feh in the background: `execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "feh /home/abc/main/violet.jpg &", NULL);`.

Comment: Create pipe, redirect `STDIN_FILENO` in child process to the read end but write nothing to the write end.

Comment: If you want both feh and the parent process to be active at the same time, you probably want to close the standard input inside `if (!pid) {...`.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fork gives the child the same open file descriptors as the parent's. Thus any characters sent to curses will also be sent to feh. [Prevent writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288062/is-close-fclose-on-stdin-guaranteed-to-be-correct) to the child's STDIN to solve the problem.

```
void display_file(void) {
    def_prog_mode();
    endwin();

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (!pid) {
        int fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
        dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd);
        execl("/usr/bin/feh", "feh", "/home/abc/main/violet.jpg", NULL);
    }

    reset_prog_mode();
    wrefresh(state_of_curses.a_win);
    wrefresh(state_of_curses.b_win);
}
```